# ASP.NET and AJAX Embedded HTML Modification

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

My project has a "HUD" on the front page that lists students that are in the process of switching course plans.  It does this by doing an AJAX call to a seperate .ascx page that runs some SQL statements in C# and renders the HTML.  It then delivers it back to the front page to be placed into a div named "dynamic".  Here's the code on the front page that calls it:

```
    function loadDynamic() {
        var ControlName = "utilities/HUD.ascx";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Result",
            data: "{controlName:'" + ControlName + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#dynamic').html(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                $('#dynamic').html(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is done in order to facilitate multiple people working on the system and being able to get live updates (there's another script that re-calls the loadDynamic() function every 10 seconds, but that's irrelevant to this problem).

However, there can be quite a few students that are trying to change course plans at one time, so in order to save space on the page, we've decided to try putting in a "...and # more records" link (an < a > tag with a javascript call in the href) that would activate another javascript function to show a seperate list with all the students and hide the list with only the few students on it (this javascript function is located on the HUD.ascx page).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadMorePending() {
        this.document.getElementById(<% =pnlMorePending.ClientID %>).style.visibility = 'visible';
        this.document.getElementById(<% =pnlPending.ClientID %>).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Now that you have the background, here's the problem:

The second code block shown above contains references to two asp:Panels, which contain the lists, located on the HUD.ascx page.  When someone clicks the "...and more" link, it should simply hide one asp:Panel and show the other.  However, when it goes to call the function, it throws a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ctl01_pnlMorePending' is undefined".  Upon further investigation (when looking at the html source after it's been rendered in the browser), even when the 'dynamic' div is populated with the data from the HUD.ascx page, it remains empty!

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

While this would explain why the pnlMorePending couldn't be found, it doesn't give me any leads on how to rectify this.  How am I supposed to reference something that doesn't exist on the page?  I've tried substituting the panels for divs, but it still doesn't work.  The problem, I think, lies in the fact that the script transfers over to the front page fine, but it doesn't run on the HUD.ascx page where it needs to.  Is there a way to do this without having 2 different HUD.ascx pages and 2 different "loadDynamic()" functions (the second being called and populated into the 'dynamic' div when the "...and more" button is pressed)?

Sorry if it's a little hard to follow.  First time posting and the problem is pretty in-depth.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes:

```
this.document.getElementById('<% =pnlMorePending.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
```